# Restore MariaDB masked service

Tags: systemd, mariadb

I have a situation where MariaDB service has become masked. This happened when a colleague tried to remove a package from an Debian 11 server. Obviously the package manager warned him but on the rush of the day he proceeded and now MariaDB service is stop and masked.

So we tried to restore the service file to restore using

```
sudo systemctl enable mariadb
```

But after that when trying to start the service

```
sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

We get error. This is the excerpt from the journalctl -xe:

```
Nov 12 07:52:32 localhost kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens192 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:4c:e1:75:dd:e0:a5:08:00 SRC=192.168.10.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=19831 PROTO=2 
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost sudo[91874]: developer : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/systemd/system ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl enable mariadb
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost sudo[91874]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by developer(uid=1000)
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: Reloading.
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: Configuration file /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: Configuration file /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. P>
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf:2: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf:3: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: Reloading.
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: Configuration file /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: Configuration file /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. P>
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf:2: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf:3: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: Configuration file /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: Configuration file /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. P>
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf:2: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf:3: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: Reloading.
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: Configuration file /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: Configuration file /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. P>
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf:2: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
Nov 12 07:53:05 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf:3: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
Nov 12 07:53:06 localhost sudo[91874]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 12 07:53:22 localhost sudo[91949]: developer : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/systemd/system ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl restart mariadb
Nov 12 07:53:22 localhost sudo[91949]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by developer(uid=1000)
Nov 12 07:53:22 localhost systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.39 database server...
 Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://www.debian.org/support
 
 A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution.
 
 The job identifier is 97288.
Nov 12 07:53:22 localhost mysqld[91957]: /usr/sbin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libsnappy.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Nov 12 07:53:22 localhost systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
 Subject: Unit process exited
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://www.debian.org/support
 
 An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mariadb.service has exited.
 
 The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 127.
Nov 12 07:53:22 localhost systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you read the log you post? `libsnappy.so.1: cannot open shared object file`

Comment: @RomeoNinov yes but I don't know what this lib is. Sorry I am o rookie o server administrator

Comment: Command `apt-file find libsnappy.so.1` will provide you the package you need to install

Comment: And your question is not for this site which is for **managing information technology systems in a business environment** Better ask your question here: https://superuser.com/ or here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this error message:

```
Nov 12 07:53:22 localhost mysqld[91957]: /usr/sbin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libsnappy.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Looks like you are missing `libsnappy.so.1`. You can install it by:

```
sudo apt install libsnappy1v5
```

Comment: Given that the system looks to be be in a really messed up state, apt install --fix-missing / apt install --fix-broken might be a better approach.